# Remove all sessions for a uid if password is changed in drupal 7.x

Tags: authentication, drupal, passwords, drupal-7

Is there any way to invalidate all other user sessions when the user does a password reset in drupal 7?
I have searched for this and so far I can only found the following resource.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2294061

Any help will be really appreciated :). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, what you want is already implemented in Drupal 7.

I've tested this on a fresh Drupal 7 install and changing the password in one browser kills all sessions for the same user in other browsers.

You can refer to the relevant source code from line **544** to **599** in this file: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/7.x/modules/user/user.module

> ```
>   // If the password changed, delete all open sessions and recreate
>   // the current one.
>   if ($account->pass != $account->original->pass) {
>     drupal_session_destroy_uid($account->uid);
>     if ($account->uid == $GLOBALS['user']->uid) {
>       drupal_session_regenerate();
>     }
>   }
> ```